# How to get three-current-positions & three-past-positions?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to find out profile's previous employment details. I have tried as per the LinkedIn's API given below.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id={id}:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,public-profile-url,industry,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,positions)?format=json&oauth2_access_token={tokenvalue}"
```

Here in above request, "id" is 1st degree connection. Then also I am never returns with the desired information after tried many times.

Can any one guide me what should I do?

Regards,
Dharmesh Solanki

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn says here that it only supports retrieving the `r_basicprofile` fields from an application.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

> For members other than the ones using your application, you may only
>   retrieve the profile fields available with the r_basicprofile member
>   permission.

Since `three-current-positions` and t`hree-past-positions` is part of the Full Profile (`r_fullprofile`), I don't think it's currently possible to get those fields for a user using the Profile API.

Unless it's for the current requesting user, ie:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,public-profile-url,industry,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,positions

Comment: It actually doesn't work either way, even if you are authenticated as the user who's fields you want to retrieve. Other posts on SO confirm that. LinkedIn, WHY?!